# Jsonwebtoken verify always return only {iat: xxx }

Tags: node.js, json-web-token, express-jwt

According to documentation, https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtverifytoken-secretorpublickey-options-callback, `jwt.verify` will returns decode payload, I run the simple script:

```
var token = jwt.sign({email: req.body.email,}, 's3cr3t');
var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 's3cr3t');
console.log(decoded)
```

but it only output like: `{ iat: 1470725598 }`

I expect the output should be like `{email: myemail@domain.com,}`

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was not able to mimic your problem until I set the property `req.body.email` to `undefined`.

**Example:**

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({email: undefined}, 's3cr3t');
var decoded = jwt.verify(token, 's3cr3t');
```

With it been undefined, the output would look like this;

> { iat: 1470727340 }

and this matches exactly what you were having which cause me to suspect your main issue was just with the property `req.body.email` been `undefined`.

Assuming `req.body.email` is correctly set to "myemail@domain.com" then the output would be;

> { email: 'myemail@domain.com', iat: 1470727500 }

Just a side note here. You might want to consider wrapping the `.verify` method inside a `try-catch` clause, as shown in the documentation. This is useful for verifying and throwing error when a token is invalid.

Comment: Remind that `email` MUST be a String, I've got the same issue because my key's value was an int and not a string (I just replaced `{ key: value }` by `{ key: \`${value}\` }`.

Answer (score 1):

I Know this is an old question but there's no clear solution that shows how to reproduce the problem. I also recently encountered the same problem: Decoded values where like {iat:xxxz}

**This is why:**

Sending a post request without the "Content-type: application/json" will result in req.body.email be undefined. That's not the value your trying to jwt.verify so the unexpected behavior.

Solved adding the "Content-type application/json" on the headers of the post request. And make sure you send de object in valid json format, properties must be like:

`{"email":"mi@email.com"}`

Answer (score 0):

The verify-function takes a third parameter, `function (err, decoded)`.
Your code should look like this:

```
jwt.verify (token, "s3cr3t", function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) throw err;

    // decoded object with your data
}
```

Comment: What OP got there is a valid example. If no callback function is specified then `jwt.verify` operates synchronously.

Comment: I see. Then, I do not see a problem with the initial code. He might aswell try this code and report if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @NikxDa, but nope :(